# Help translating この姿なら異国人も怪しまれない. Why も instead of でも?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, particle-も, particle-でも

この姿（すがた）なら異国人(いこくじん）も怪（あや）しまれない is a phrase said to someone disguised as a catholic missionary in medieval era in Japan, so he is not suspected by having a western face in the asian country.

I saw a lot of questions here about も vs でも, but generally speaking, the answer of the questions is that も means  "also" and でも means "even", with the も particle playing the role of the が or を particle, including a subject or object in a list to interact with the verb, while the でも particle ephasizes an element on a list as being against the odds.

But in the phrase この姿なら異国人も怪しまれない, using that logic, も does not seem to fit. It does not makes sense if 異国人 is a subject of the passive form of the verb 怪しむ, because then 異国人 would be the person being suspected by someone, and not what someone is being suspected of, what makes more sense by the context.

An user in another japanese language forum translated it as "with that outfit, you won't be suspected even being a foreigner", what for me would make sense if the phrase had a でも instead of も.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

異国人 *is* the subject of the verb 怪しまれる, i.e., 異国人 *is* the one being potentially suspected by someone else. この姿なら異国人**も**怪しまれない is simply この姿なら異国人**は**怪しまれない with は replaced by も. The object of 怪しむ can be either a person or a property of a person.

> この姿なら異国人**も**怪しまれない。
> (Japanese people won't be suspected because they are Japanese, but) *also* foreigners won't be suspected if they look like this.

この姿なら異国人**でも**怪しまれない is also perfectly fine, and the difference in meaning is subtle. If you had explicitly asked for a super-literal, word-by-word translation, the user in the other forum might have given a different translation respecting the difference between も and でも.

Comment: I thought it was いくにじん because those kanjis appear together on my keyboard  when I type like this. But now I saw on Jisho app the correct reading.

Comment: Sorry. Looking at your explanation, I don't know why it was not making sense to me the 異国人 to be the subject of the 怪しまれない. Actually, when I wrote the phrase the in way I liked, with でも, it points the person as being 異国人, so the person being the subject on the original phrase shouldn't have been be a problem to me. And yet it took a long time now thinking to realize this.